# Flaw in iOS WebGL texture rendering

Tags: javascript, ios, webgl

This simple test of WebGL texture rendering using the three.js library:

```js
// Canvas dimensions

canvasW = Math.floor(0.9*window.innerWidth);
canvasH = Math.floor(0.75*canvasW);
cAR = canvasW / canvasH;
canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
canvasWrapper.style.width=canvasW+'px';
canvasWrapper.style.height=canvasH+'px';

// Renderer

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
console.log("Renderer pixel ratio = "+window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(canvasW, canvasH);
canvas = renderer.domElement;
canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);

// Set up camera

cameraDist = 24;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, cAR, 0.01, 1000);
cameraAngle = 0;
camera.position.x = cameraDist*Math.sin(cameraAngle);
camera.position.y = 0.3*cameraDist;
camera.position.z = cameraDist*Math.cos(cameraAngle);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

// Set up scene, consisting of texture-tiled ground

scene = new THREE.Scene();
groundWidth = 1000;
groundMaterial = null;
groundGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(groundWidth,groundWidth);
groundGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI/2);
groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeom, groundMaterial || new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
scene.add(groundMesh);
//window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// Insert texture once it has loaded

function setGroundTexture(texture)
{
  groundTexture = texture;
  groundTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.repeat.set(groundWidth, groundWidth);
  groundTexture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
  console.log("Texture anisotropy = "+groundTexture.anisotropy);
  groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: groundTexture});
  if (groundMesh)
  {
    groundMesh.material = groundMaterial;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
}

// Start texture loading

//new THREE.TextureLoader().load("Texture.png", setGroundTexture, function (xhr) {}, function (xhr) {});
setGroundTexture(makeTexture());

// Render a frame

function draw()
{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// -------

function makeTexture() {
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = 256;
  ctx.canvas.height = 256;
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(238, 238, 238)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(208, 208, 208)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.fillRect(128, 128, 128, 128);
  for (var y = 0; y < 2; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(x * 128 + 64, y * 128 + 64);
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.beginPath();
      var radius = 50;
      ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
      for (var i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
        var a = i / 3 * Math.PI;
        ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(a) * radius, Math.sin(a) * radius);
      }
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
  var tex = new THREE.Texture(ctx.canvas);
  tex.needsUpdate = true;
  return tex;
}
```

```css
canvas, #canvasWrapper {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r78/three.js"></script>
<div id="canvasWrapper"></div>
```

renders perfectly on the desktop browsers I've tried, but is badly blurred when rendered on an iPad, as shown by the screenshot further down the page.

Desktop

[image]

iPad

[image]

In both cases, the texture is rendered with an anisotropy of 16 (the maximum supported by the renderer).  The image used for the texture has dimensions 256 × 256 (a power of 2, which is necessary for repeated textures), and making it larger or smaller doesn't fix the problem.

texture:

[image]

I'm setting the renderer's pixel ratio to match the browser window, which means it is 1 for desktop systems and 2 for the iPad's retina display.  This approach generally gives the best results for other aspects of rendering, and in any case setting the pixel ratio to 1 on the iPad, instead of 2, doesn't improve the appearance of the texture.

So my question is:  is this a bug in iOS WebGL that I'll just have to live with, or is there something I can tweak in my own code to get better results on iOS devices?

**Edit:** This three.js [demo page](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_anisotropy.html) also renders much less clearly on the iPad than on desktop browsers, and the source for the demo uses the same general approach as my own code, which suggests that whatever trick I'm missing, it's not something simple and obvious.

Comment: I am unable to repo your issues. https://imgur.com/a/x8H4w
What version of iOS? Which iPad? Do you have any magnification settings on in the iOS settings?

Comment: @gman The issue is the same for me under iOS 9 and iOS 10.  I'm using an iPad 4 with retina display (2048 × 1536).  No magnification in any iOS settings (I guess you mean Accessibility zoom?)  I get the same kind of artifacts for your code with a script-generated texture.

Comment: @gman Here is a screenshot of the three.js demo on my iPad 4:  http://gregegan.customer.netspace.net.au/tmp/iPadDemo.png with odd zig-zagging of the dark lines between the planks.  Weirdly, though, I don't have any problems on the same iPad with this WebGL demo:  http://media.tojicode.com/webgl-samples/anisotropy.html  Is anyone else with an iPad 4 reading this ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg Egan's observation makes a lot of sense. If you not only subdivide the plane but tile the UV coords so they repeat instead of using large numbers that might fix it.

```js
// Canvas dimensions

canvasW = Math.floor(0.9*window.innerWidth);
canvasH = Math.floor(0.75*canvasW);
cAR = canvasW / canvasH;
canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
canvasWrapper.style.width=canvasW+'px';
canvasWrapper.style.height=canvasH+'px';

// Renderer

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
console.log("Renderer pixel ratio = "+window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(canvasW, canvasH);
canvas = renderer.domElement;
canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);

// Set up camera

cameraDist = 24;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, cAR, 0.01, 1000);
cameraAngle = 0;
camera.position.x = cameraDist*Math.sin(cameraAngle);
camera.position.y = 0.3*cameraDist;
camera.position.z = cameraDist*Math.cos(cameraAngle);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

// Set up scene, consisting of texture-tiled ground

scene = new THREE.Scene();
// groundWidth = 1000;
// Reduce overall size of ground
groundWidth = 200;
groundMaterial = null;
// groundGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(groundWidth,groundWidth);
// Split plane geometry into a grid of smaller squares
//groundGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(groundWidth,groundWidth,20,20);
var groundGeom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

var quads = groundWidth * groundWidth;
var positions = new Float32Array( quads * 6 * 3 );
var normals = new Float32Array( quads * 6 * 3 );
var texcoords = new Float32Array( quads * 6 * 2 );

for (var yy = 0; yy < groundWidth; ++yy) {
  for (var xx = 0; xx < groundWidth; ++xx) {
    var qoff = (yy * groundWidth + xx) * 6;
    var poff = qoff * 3;
    var x = xx - groundWidth / 2;
    var y = yy - groundWidth / 2;
    positions[poff +  0] = x;
    positions[poff +  1] = y;
    positions[poff +  2] = 0;
    
    positions[poff +  3] = x + 1;
    positions[poff +  4] = y;
    positions[poff +  5] = 0;
    
    positions[poff +  6] = x;
    positions[poff +  7] = y + 1;
    positions[poff +  8] = 0;

    positions[poff +  9] = x;
    positions[poff + 10] = y + 1;
    positions[poff + 11] = 0;
    
    positions[poff + 12] = x + 1;
    positions[poff + 13] = y;
    positions[poff + 14] = 0;
    
    positions[poff + 15] = x + 1;
    positions[poff + 16] = y + 1;
    positions[poff + 17] = 0;
    
    normals[poff +  0] = 0;
    normals[poff +  1] = 1;
    normals[poff +  2] = 0;
    
    normals[poff +  3] = 0;
    normals[poff +  4] = 1;
    normals[poff +  5] = 0;
    
    normals[poff +  6] = 0;
    normals[poff +  7] = 1;
    normals[poff +  8] = 0;

    normals[poff +  9] = 0;
    normals[poff + 10] = 1;
    normals[poff + 11] = 0;
    
    normals[poff + 12] = 0;
    normals[poff + 13] = 1;
    normals[poff + 14] = 0;
    
    normals[poff + 15] = 0;
    normals[poff + 16] = 1;
    normals[poff + 17] = 0;
    
    var toff = qoff * 2;

    texcoords[toff +  0] = 0;
    texcoords[toff +  1] = 0;
    
    texcoords[toff +  2] = 1;
    texcoords[toff +  3] = 0;
    
    texcoords[toff +  4] = 0;
    texcoords[toff +  5] = 1;

    texcoords[toff +  6] = 0;
    texcoords[toff +  7] = 1;
    
    texcoords[toff +  8] = 1;
    texcoords[toff +  9] = 0;
    
    texcoords[toff + 10] = 1;
    texcoords[toff + 11] = 1;
  }
}

groundGeom.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ) );
groundGeom.addAttribute( 'normal', new THREE.BufferAttribute( normals, 3 ) );
groundGeom.addAttribute( 'uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute( texcoords, 2 ) );

groundGeom.computeBoundingSphere();

groundGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI/2);
groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeom, groundMaterial || new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
scene.add(groundMesh);
//window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// Insert texture once it has loaded

function setGroundTexture(texture)
{
  groundTexture = texture;
  groundTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.repeat.set(1, 1);
  groundTexture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
  console.log("Texture anisotropy = "+groundTexture.anisotropy);
  groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: groundTexture});
  if (groundMesh)
  {
    groundMesh.material = groundMaterial;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
}

// Start texture loading

//new THREE.TextureLoader().load("Texture.png", setGroundTexture, function (xhr) {}, function (xhr) {});
setGroundTexture(makeTexture());

// Render a frame

function draw()
{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// -------

function makeTexture() {
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = 256;
  ctx.canvas.height = 256;
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(238, 238, 238)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(208, 208, 208)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.fillRect(128, 128, 128, 128);
  for (var y = 0; y < 2; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(x * 128 + 64, y * 128 + 64);
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.beginPath();
      var radius = 50;
      ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
      for (var i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
        var a = i / 3 * Math.PI;
        ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(a) * radius, Math.sin(a) * radius);
      }
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
  var tex = new THREE.Texture(ctx.canvas);
  tex.needsUpdate = true;
  return tex;
}
```

```css
canvas, #canvasWrapper {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r78/three.js"></script>
<div id="canvasWrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Great!  This version works beautifully on the iPad 4, and though just shrinking the size from 1000 to 200 gives a big improvement, this extra step raises the quality further.

Answer (score 3):

I can't fully explain the source of the problem, but I've found a work-around that suggests that the cause is some kind of degradation of numerical precision, I guess in the GPU, that doesn't occur with every iPad graphics card.

The work-around involves splitting the plane geometry for the ground, which was originally just a single square (which three.js presumably divides into 2 triangles), into a grid of multiple squares.  Presumably this changes something in the way the (u,v) coordinates on the object and the texture coordinates run up against the limits of floating point precision in the GPU.  Also, reducing the size of the ground from 1000 to 200 helps.

The annoying thing is the overhead from having all those extra faces in the plane geometry, even though they're completely redundant in specifying the shape.

In any case, the result looks exactly the same on my desktop browsers, but vastly better on my iPad 4.

**Edit:** After more careful testing, I don't think subdividing the `THREE.PlaneGeometry` is making any difference, it's only reducing the *overall size* of the tiled plane that helps.  And in fact, by making the size of the tiled plane **large** enough, whatever limit is being hit on the iPad 4 when the size is just 1000 can be reached on my iMac when the size is 80,000, as the second version of the code snippet shows.  (The texture starts to degrade around 50,000, but 80,000 makes the distortion unmissable.)  Obviously there are no real applications where you need to tile a surface with 50,000 x 50,000 copies of a texture, but a few hundred in each direction, which is where the iPad 4 starts to have problems, isn't extravagant.

**First version of the code snippet, which fixes the problem on an iPad 4:**

```js
// Canvas dimensions

canvasW = Math.floor(0.9*window.innerWidth);
canvasH = Math.floor(0.75*canvasW);
cAR = canvasW / canvasH;
canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
canvasWrapper.style.width=canvasW+'px';
canvasWrapper.style.height=canvasH+'px';

// Renderer

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
console.log("Renderer pixel ratio = "+window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(canvasW, canvasH);
canvas = renderer.domElement;
canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);

// Set up camera

cameraDist = 24;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, cAR, 0.01, 1000);
cameraAngle = 0;
camera.position.x = cameraDist*Math.sin(cameraAngle);
camera.position.y = 0.3*cameraDist;
camera.position.z = cameraDist*Math.cos(cameraAngle);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

// Set up scene, consisting of texture-tiled ground

scene = new THREE.Scene();
// groundWidth = 1000;
// Reduce overall size of ground
groundWidth = 200;
groundMaterial = null;
// groundGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(groundWidth,groundWidth);
// Split plane geometry into a grid of smaller squares
groundGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(groundWidth,groundWidth,20,20);
groundGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI/2);
groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeom, groundMaterial || new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
scene.add(groundMesh);
//window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// Insert texture once it has loaded

function setGroundTexture(texture)
{
  groundTexture = texture;
  groundTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.repeat.set(groundWidth, groundWidth);
  groundTexture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
  console.log("Texture anisotropy = "+groundTexture.anisotropy);
  groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: groundTexture});
  if (groundMesh)
  {
    groundMesh.material = groundMaterial;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
}

// Start texture loading

//new THREE.TextureLoader().load("Texture.png", setGroundTexture, function (xhr) {}, function (xhr) {});
setGroundTexture(makeTexture());

// Render a frame

function draw()
{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// -------

function makeTexture() {
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = 256;
  ctx.canvas.height = 256;
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(238, 238, 238)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(208, 208, 208)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.fillRect(128, 128, 128, 128);
  for (var y = 0; y < 2; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(x * 128 + 64, y * 128 + 64);
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.beginPath();
      var radius = 50;
      ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
      for (var i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
        var a = i / 3 * Math.PI;
        ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(a) * radius, Math.sin(a) * radius);
      }
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
  var tex = new THREE.Texture(ctx.canvas);
  tex.needsUpdate = true;
  return tex;
}
```

```css
canvas, #canvasWrapper {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r78/three.js"></script>
<div id="canvasWrapper"></div>
```

**Second version of the code snippet, which breaks the texture on a 2007 iMac:**

```js
// Canvas dimensions

canvasW = Math.floor(0.9*window.innerWidth);
canvasH = Math.floor(0.75*canvasW);
cAR = canvasW / canvasH;
canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('canvasWrapper');
canvasWrapper.style.width=canvasW+'px';
canvasWrapper.style.height=canvasH+'px';

// Renderer

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
console.log("Renderer pixel ratio = "+window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(canvasW, canvasH);
canvas = renderer.domElement;
canvasWrapper.appendChild(canvas);

// Set up camera

cameraDist = 24;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25, cAR, 0.01, 1000);
cameraAngle = 0;
camera.position.x = cameraDist*Math.sin(cameraAngle);
camera.position.y = 0.3*cameraDist;
camera.position.z = cameraDist*Math.cos(cameraAngle);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

// Set up scene, consisting of texture-tiled ground

scene = new THREE.Scene();
// groundWidth = 1000;
// Increase the size of the plane to trigger the problem
groundWidth = 80000;
groundMaterial = null;
groundGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(groundWidth,groundWidth);
groundGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI/2);
groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeom, groundMaterial || new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());
scene.add(groundMesh);
//window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

// Insert texture once it has loaded

function setGroundTexture(texture)
{
  groundTexture = texture;
  groundTexture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.repeat.set(groundWidth, groundWidth);
  groundTexture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
  console.log("Texture anisotropy = "+groundTexture.anisotropy);
  groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: groundTexture});
  if (groundMesh)
  {
    groundMesh.material = groundMaterial;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  };
}

// Start texture loading

//new THREE.TextureLoader().load("Texture.png", setGroundTexture, function (xhr) {}, function (xhr) {});
setGroundTexture(makeTexture());

// Render a frame

function draw()
{
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// -------

function makeTexture() {
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = 256;
  ctx.canvas.height = 256;
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(238, 238, 238)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 256, 256);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(208, 208, 208)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.fillRect(128, 128, 128, 128);
  for (var y = 0; y < 2; ++y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(x * 128 + 64, y * 128 + 64);
      ctx.lineWidth = 3;
      ctx.beginPath();
      var radius = 50;
      ctx.moveTo(radius, 0);
      for (var i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
        var a = i / 3 * Math.PI;
        ctx.lineTo(Math.cos(a) * radius, Math.sin(a) * radius);
      }
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
  var tex = new THREE.Texture(ctx.canvas);
  tex.needsUpdate = true;
  return tex;
}
```

```css
canvas, #canvasWrapper {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r78/three.js"></script>
<div id="canvasWrapper"></div>
```